# Nature words ending in -land

Tags: single-word-requests, toponyms

What do you call nature words ending in -land? For example, moorland, wetland, marshland, woodland...You get the picture. Is there a name for such things? And is there one for a place that is surrounded by water/made up of shores of lakes/rivers/streams besides wetland?

Comment: As for your second question, *marshland* and *swampland* both exist.

Comment: Or an ....is*land*?? ;-)

Comment: Why would there be a word to encompass such different geographic phenomena based on the fact that they happen to have the same suffix? As Jim says, there's also _island_, and I'll add _wasteland_, _inland_, _highland_, or even _England_ if you want to take it even further. They really have nothing useful in common except the suffix.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: And don't forget Disneyland!

Comment: You can coin *landonym*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that a word specific to your meaning exists in English.

Certainly, one can use **land form**, **habitat** or even **ecosystem**. But there is nothing about those terms that restricts members of the set to only include terms ending in *-land*.

There are many such terms, including:

- moorland
- wetland
- marshland
- woodland
- swampland
- highland
- lowland

Interestingly, many of these have forms that can exist without the suffix, such as:

- moor
- marsh
- swamp
- wood (or woods)

There are, of course, also many counterexamples—those words that end in *-land* but don't really capture the sense of a geographic form or natural habitat as you are describing. For example (including some from the comments, with thanks):

- England
- Iceland
- Disneyland (ha! thanks, Drew)

Comment: If you're easily distracted, there are 10 UN Member States whose names end in "-land"

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[terrain](http://tfd.com/terrain)**

> 1.a. An area of land; ground: climbed a tree to view the surrounding terrain.
>   b. A particular geographic area; a region: a guide who knows this terrain well.
>   2. The surface features of an area of land; topography: boots designed for rugged terrain.